# downloading a CSV file without a direct link or API

Tags: python, excel, csv, vba

I am trying to find a solution to download a CSV file from an internal company website.

My first thought was throught the API but it doesn't exit, at least not yet.

Second I figured, I would try a direct link to the CSV file on the website, that's also a No Go as the link is sort of static and even copy pasting to a new tab doesn't work.

My third idea was to record a mouse movement, but that's just too inefficient as I would like this process to happen in the background.

Please, I welcome any ideas, codes, software, anything.... most preferable solution would be in VBA after that python and then anything else.

I'm sorry if this is not stack overflow worthy question :/

Comment: You can automate a browser with selenium and python. Sounds like it would be easiest solution.

Comment: can you share a sample code showing the structure

Comment: unfortunately not, like I said the two solutions I had in mind don't work for the stated reasons. Im not looking for free code, just an idea, a push in the right direction